AWS Prefix Hierarchy vs Request Rate Limit: Does request to A/B/C count against A/B and A/?
There is something that is quite unclear to me about aws s3 prefixes, which i would hope someone could help me with.
I am wondering if when i have the prefixes
A/B/C/
and
A/B/D/
Any request against A/B/C/ or A/B/D/ count against A/B/ and ultimately A/ in term of request rate ?
Hence that the parent prefix limit apply to the child prefix.

Please refer this similar question for more details S3 - What Exactly Is A Prefix? And what Ratelimits apply?
Based on response from AWS support as below,

Earlier S3 supported 100 PUT/LIST/DELETE requests per second and 300
GET requests per second. To achieve higher performance, a random hash
/ prefix schema had to be implemented. Since last year the request
rate limits increased to 3,500 PUT/POST/DELETE and 5,500 GET requests
per second. This increase is often enough for applications to mitigate
503 SlowDown errors without having to randomize prefixes.
However, if the new limits are not sufficient, prefixes would need to
be used. A prefix has no fixed number of characters. It is any string
between a bucket name and an object name, for example:

bucket/folder1/sub1/file
bucket/folder1/sub2/file
bucket/1/file
bucket/2/file

Prefixes of the object 'file' would be: /folder1/sub1/ ,
/folder1/sub2/, /1/, /2/. In this example, if you spread reads across
all four prefixes evenly, you can achieve 22,000 requests per second.

It means each of your prefixes A/B/C/ and A/B/D/ has separate limit, and these prefixes are not adding limit towards root prefixes A/B/ and A/
Also refer: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/using-prefixes.html for Organizing objects using prefixes

Essentially
bucket/folder1/sub1/file
bucket/folder1/sub2/file
are independent prefix says it all ?

these are file path of bucket, but yes @MattDeamon
/folder1/sub1/
/folder1/sub2/ are independent prefixes
similar example is mentioned here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/using-prefixes.html, where few examples are representing prefix management for cities in country
Europe/France/Nouvelle-Aquitaine/Bordeaux
North America/Canada/Quebec/Montreal
North America/USA/Washington/Bellevue
North America/USA/Washington/Seattle
these each represents independent prefixes

Although "/A/B/C" and "/A" look like a OS style path to a file, I thnk of them more as key to objects. It makes sense them to count them as separate requests:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/object-keys.html
